# Understanding & Additional code for excel row copy based on value

Tags: excel, copy, row

Please see below code I have found on the internet, which is currently working to a certain degree for me.

Could someone possibly commentate on what each line of this code means so I can understand what its doing?

Im trying to understand it with little programming knowledge and add additional code to look for additional values to paste into additional sheets.

I'm also trying to work out how to make them paste to certain rows one after the other and not maintain the row they were originally in on sheet 1.

Code:

```
Sub Test()
Dim rw As Long, Cell As Range
For Each Cell In Sheets(1).Range("H:H")
rw = Cell.Row
 If Cell.Value = "Dept 1" Then
  Cell.EntireRow.Copy
   Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & rw).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
 End If
Next
End Sub
```

--

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added comments as requested. To paste them onto the same row, look at removing the `rw` variable and replacing it with something that increments by one each time

```
 Sub Test()
        'declare variables
        Dim rw As Long, Cell As Range
        'loop through each cell the whole of column H in the first worksheet in the active workbook
        For Each Cell In Sheets(1).Range("H:H")
            'set rw variable equal to the row number of the Cell variable, which changes with each iteration of the For loop above
            rw = Cell.Row
            'check if the value of Cell variable equals Dept 1
            If Cell.Value = "Dept 1" Then
               'copy the entire row if above is true
               Cell.EntireRow.Copy
               'paste to the same row of Sheet 2
               Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & rw).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your Code Commented hope you understand:

---

Sub Test()

' Variables Defined as follows:
   Dim rw As Long, Cell As Range
' Loop Searching each Cell of (Range H1 to end of last H on sheet1
For Each Cell In Sheets(1).Range("H:H")
  ' now determine current row number:
      rw = Cell.Row
' Test cell value if it contain >> Dept 1 as value:
     If Cell.Value = "Dept 1" Then
' Select that row and copy it:
        Cell.EntireRow.Copy
' now paste the values of that row into A column and rw row on sheet2:

```
   Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & rw).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

' You should add following to:
  '    Disable marching ants around copied range:
          Application.CutCopyMode = False

End If
Next
End Sub